# Unable to access a JSON object as I would expect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/foo/getData',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            lat = data.project_x;
            lng = data.project_y;
            zoomin = parseInt(data.mapzoom);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

and return:

```
[{"id":"3","project_x":"42.456","project_y":"-70.123","zoom":"7"},{"id":"3","project_x":"41.123","project_y":"-71.456","zoom":"7"}]
```

`console.log(data)` gives me:

```
Object 
id: "3"
project_x: "42.456"
project_y: "-70.123"
```

Yet when I try to assign these values to something I get `undefined`. Example:
console.log(data.project_x);

returns `undefined` when I would expect it to return `42.456`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is it because data is an array of json? maybe console.log(data[0].project_x);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your result is an array you need to access the position you want, for example:

```
lat = data[0].project_x;
```

Or, depending on your needs, loop through the array and use each value...it's unclear from your code exactly what you're after, but the important part is the properties aren't on the object returned...they're on objects *in the array* that was returned.

A loop could look like:

```
$.each(data, function() {
   alert(this.project_x); //access properties off this
});
```